# Can i Use HTML 5 Canvas as an image?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas

Here  Instead of image the canvas needs to be used

```
$('img').selectAreas({

});
```

HTML:

```
<canvas width="500" height="405.08149568552255" style="margin-top: -202.541px; margin-left: -250px;" data-caman-id="91"></canvas>
```

This canvas needs to be used instead of image. Its function is to select an area of image formed by Canvas.

Comment: If you are talking about [this plugin](https://github.com/360Learning/jquery-select-areas/), and that there is a missing feature, you may want to [open an issue](https://github.com/360Learning/jquery-select-areas/issues/new) in the project's issue tracker.

Comment: I need to know can it be used with canvas

Comment: Can canvas be used for such purpose using some other plugin

Comment: The code you offer does not attempt to do what you desire so your question is a design issue rather than a coding issue. Stackoverflow deals with specific coding issues rather than design phase issues so your design question is not appropriate for Stackoverflow. **Please delete your (off-topic) design question**, but please do come back for help if/when you have a question about your existing code. :-) FYI, 
 Yes, you can very easily draw an image onto an html5 canvas and listen for mouse events to allow the user to select a subsection of the image

Comment: Have you read it properly .Its a code issue.I am not able to understand how to code to code it in a right way.